# MySQL Not Starting on Mac Even Though it is Installed Using Brew

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

In Apple Preferences I can see the MySQL icon. when I click on it it says it cannot be started.

[image]

On the terminal I can see that MySQL is already installed using brew:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Any ideas why I cannot start mysql server?

when I try to jump into the mysql prompt from Mac terminal I get the following:

```
sudo mysql -u root
Password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

UPDATE:

```
mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Jason-MacBook-Pro:fe$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: can you run `which mysql` command and paste the o/p ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command `which mysql` on command prompt, it will o/p like something. `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`. then confirm that no existing `mysql` process is running by using `ps aux | grep mysql` command. then if no process if running, start **mysql** from command line with below command :-

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
```

After that again confirm with command `ps aux | grep mysql` and mac preference setting, mysql should be up and running.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Amit! I was able to resolve my issue by renaming the mysql-version-number folder to mysql folder name. But now I am getting trouble getting into the mysql command prompt. Is there any GUI tool that I can use to create mysql database.

Comment: what error u getting ? how you are getting into mysql command prompt, can u paste the command here ?

Comment: I don't even know how to get into the mysql command prompt. Please check the original question I have updated it to add the code.

Comment: @johndoe please run `mysql -uroot` and then provide your `root` passwd if you set any.